# "Master" feature?

Tags: feature-activation

I'm building a complex application that is composed by multiples features of different kind.

I want to avoid having all features individually able to be activated from the site admin page.

What my options (Sandboxed solution is not available) ?

I can see three solutions, all consisting in hiding features (HIDDEN=true) :

- Activate all features from a PS script
- Create a custom site template, and specify all features in the onet.xml. This will breaks features stappling I fear
- Create a "Master" feature, visible, that only performs other features activation

What is the best solution ? Is there any other solution I missed ?

ps: sp 2010 enterprise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the idea of hiding all of your features and having one un-hidden feature that activates the hidden ones.

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time and have even written my own SPFeatureReceiver class to streamline the creation of such features.

The workhorse of the class though is really just this:

```
foreach (Guid id in FeatureGuids)
{
    if (oWeb.Features[id] == null)
    {
        oWeb.Features.Add(id);
    }
}
```

Where FeatureGuids is just a list of web scoped feature GUIDs (The guid can be found in the feature manifest file). SPSite also has a features collection that you can do this on.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, one might ask the question why you're breaking it up into many features if they are all dependant on each other and hidden - Why not just deploy them as a single feature? There's no requirement to have different things in different features (Except where they have to be deployed at different levels - farm/webapp/site/web).

But, if you must do it like this, do ensure that the solution/feature dependancies are defined. Scripting or having a 'master' feature would be down to your preference - I'm not aware of any best practise regarding this (although I would probably script the feature activation myself).

Comment: Marcus, I have to split into several features for two reasons: mainly because of the different scopes of features (site and web), and sometimes because of the <s>awful</s> lookup definitions between several of my list

Comment: Fair enough. I mention it because I've seen people go crazy in the past (1 feature per artifact).In a project a while ago, the developer had ended up with 30+ features and was wondering why solution deployment was so complicated...

Comment: Solution deployment should still be easy in this respect. All your features should be grouped into solutions (WSPs) where it makes sense. Most of my projects have 2 or 3. One common WSP that I reuse in all projects and one or two that are project specific.